How can I set a value in web.config for error "This request has been blocked because sensitive information used in a GET request"?
I am capturing errors in a rest call and returning a Json. The error gets written away to a third party logging site.
Something like the following:
var client = new Bugsnag.Client(new Bugsnag.Configuration("KEY"));
client.Notify(new Exception("Error:" + ex.Message ));                
return Json(new { success = false, error = ex.Message });

But after this it goes to the global error handling in Application_Error()
protected void Application_Error()
{
    var ex = Server.GetLastError();
    // ....
}

And it doesn't capture the error:

This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request. To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet

I have to change the last line to
return Json(new { success = false, error = ex.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);   

for it to send the error.
I don't want to really do this for all the requests.
Is there any setting I can put in web.config or the like to put in the JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet instead of overriding all my REST call routines  as there are hundreds of them?

Maybe implement an action filter like this answer on Why is JsonRequestBehavior needed??
